# finding the values of m, using roots

Tags: roots

Consider the equation $4x^2 − mx − m = 0 $ (with unknown x).

Find the values of m such that the equation has

(a) one (double) root;

(b) two distinct (real) roots;

(c) no real roots.

**My working out**

$4x^2 − mx − m = 0 $

Apply the quadratic formula gives

$m+/-\sqrt{m^2+4m\:-16} / 2(4)$

a) $m^2 +4m − 16 = 0 $

Through completing the square I get:

$(m + 2)^2 -20 = 0$

$m = -2$

b)$m^2 + 4m − 16 > 0$

$(m + 2)^2 -20 > 0$

$m+2> 0$

I can't seem to find more solutions

c) $m^2 + 4m − 16 < 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HINT:** Consider the discriminant $D=b^2 - 4ac$. Then $ax^2 + bx + c = 0$ has two different real solution iff $D>0$, double root iff $D=0$ and complex roots iff $D<0$

---

The solutions of inequalities are wrong. Try to solve $m^2 + 4m - 16=0$ and write $m^2 + 4m - 16 = (m-m_1)(m-m_2)$, where $m_1,m_2$ are the solutions of the equation. Then we have that:

$$m^2 + 4m - 16 >0 \iff (m-m_1)> 0 \text{ and } (m-m_2)>0 \text{ or } (m-m_1)< 0 \text{ and } (m-m_2)<0$$

$$m^2 + 4m - 16 =0 \iff (m-m_1)= 0 \text{ or } (m-m_2)=0$$

$$m^2 + 4m - 16 <0 \iff (m-m_1)< 0 \text{ and } (m-m_2)>0 \text{ or } (m-m_1)> 0 \text{ and } (m-m_2)<0$$

Comment: That makes sense however the equation cannot be factorise easily and requires using completing the square for $m^2+4m−16=(m−m1)(m−m2)$ how would you find the solutions with completing the square

Comment: @Maggie Use the quadratic formula to get that $m_1 = -2 + \sqrt{20}$ and $m_2 = -2 - \sqrt{20}$

Comment: @Maggie By completing the square we have:

$$0 = m^2 + 4m - 16 = (m+2)^2 - 20 \iff (m+2)^2 = 20$$ 
$$\iff m+2 = \pm \sqrt{20} \iff m = -2 \pm \sqrt{20}$$

Comment: That's the discriminant, not determinant.

Comment: I am slightly confused so if it is one(double) root $b2−4ac = 0$, two distinct (real) roots $b2−4ac > 0$ and no real roots (complex) $b2−4ac < 0$

Comment: @BillDubuque what is difference?

Comment: @Maggie Yeah, you're right